# devexpress textbox search not functioning

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, devexpress

I tried the devexpress textbox outside the gridview table to search for data with EQPID but when i typed EQPID on textbox, the gridview table still remain the same.

ASPx

```
<dx:ASPxTextBox ID="tb1" runat="server" Width="170px" OnTextChanged="ASPxTextBox1_TextChanged">
</dx:ASPxTextBox>
```

C#

```
     protected void ASPxTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cn"].ConnectionString))
        {
            if (cn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                cn.Open();
            }
                            using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select EQPID,RULETYPE,RULENAME,seqNo,SUM(CNT) as CNT,SUM(WFS_QTY) as QTY,(Select SUM(WFS_QTY) from RANK_DECISIVE where EQPtype = 'IASCAN' and DATADATE = '2018/06/12') as TTL_QTY From(Select t1.EQPID, t1.RULETYPE, t1.RULENAME, t1.CNT, t1.WFS_QTY, isNull(t2.rankingIndex, 999) as seqNo from(select a.EQPID, a.RULETYPE, a.RULENAME, a.CNT, a.WFS_QTY, b.ruleName as reportName from RANK_DECISIVE a, station b where a.EQPtype = 'IASCAN' and a.DATADATE = '2018/06/12' and a.EQPID = b.StationName) t1 left join rankingRule t2 on t1.reportName = t2.ReportName and t1.RULETYPE = t2.ruleName and t1.RULENAME = t2.reason) t3 Where EQPID LIKE ('%" + tb1.Text + "%') Group by EQPID, RULETYPE, RULENAME, seqNo ", cn))
            {
                da.Fill(dt);
                Grid.DataSource = dt;
                Grid.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: Any errors can be shown? As a side note for security, please avoid string concatenations for making up SQL queries, use parameterized query instead.

Comment: it showed this "An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Where'."

Comment: Try to run same query in SSMS with pre-assigned value picked from `tb1.Text`. Have you get same error and where? Possibly the last `WHERE` clause with string concatenation causing incorrect syntax, including missing a parenthesis `(` or `)`.

Comment: Sorry that I am new to this, i don't get what is ssms with pre-assigned valued picked? You mean the parenthesis after like?

Comment: You can replace `tb1.Text` with any value you want, such like `WHERE EQPID Like '%something%'`. Run the query in SSMS and watch for any errors. If the error shows up, provide the position where the error occurs.

Comment: I tried to run on ssms but it only shows the where and group by sequence error, then i swap the position the query back to normal. I tried the code on devexpress, typed something on the textbox and entered, the gridview table still remain the same.